# How to fill a color to the spines and keep a margin for the data bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to color all the negative area of my graph (below the y=0 axis).

The function `facecolor` is setting it for the whole graph. Then, I tried to use `fill_between` but it get white space because of the margin, even if I add it to the max values of the axis.

Here is my current plot (to reproduce the screenshot below):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# loading file

for row in file:
    # getting x, y, color and label from row
    plt.plot(x, y, color=color, linewidth = 3,
         marker='|', markerfacecolor=color, markersize=12, label=label) 
    # x = [-a, b] and y = [c, c] making only horizontal lines with two points (one negative and one positive)

plt.axvline(x=0, color="k", linestyle='dashed')
plt.axhline(y=0, color="r", linewidth=4)

xmarg, ymarg = plt.margins()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = plt.axis()
ax.fill_between([xmin-xmarg, xmax+xmarg], ymin-ymarg, 0, color='lightgray')
```

But the background colour is not sticking the viewport borders (left, right and bottom), there is still a margin. If I remove the margin with `ax.margins(0)`, it works. But I want to keep them to avoid my graph plot sticking the border.

You can see in the picture below the margins:

[image: The result I have right now]

So, how to fill the background colour of my graph below the abscissa, without margin/padding?

If I remove the margin, my data lines are sticking to the border, I don't want that. I want to keep the margin between the data and the axis. But I want to fill the background colour of the lower half of the viewport, not the data area only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Reduce the margins to 0 with `ax.margins(0)`
- Use `.set_xlim` and `.set_ylim` to have a buffer space between the end of the data bars, and the left, right, and bottom spines.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(-5, 5), range(-5, 5))

# change xlim and ylim to add a buffer between the spine and data bars
ax.set_ylim(-5.5, 4.5)
ax.set_xlim(-5.5, 4.5)

# remove the margins
ax.margins(0)

# fill to the spines
ax.fill_between((-5.5, 4.5), -5.5, 0, color='purple', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]